# System is running in low-graphics mode: 13.10

Tags: drivers, graphics

Been trying all the different answers out there about this issue and still have nothing working. I ran the updates today, April 5th, and upon rebooting I started getting this error. I'm running on an Asus ultrabook (Intel graphics) so none of the nvidia/ati "solutions" really help. Someone mentioned downloading the repos for the unstable intel drivers but that doesn't work either. Nothing seems to help recover the system. Is there anything special to be done for Intel graphics computers that will help here?

Other things I tried:

- reinstalling lightdm
- removing all nvidia files and reinstalling them

Answer (score 0):

If you have nvidia optimus inside your laptop try to generate new x server configuration by using nvidia-xconfig as a root.

Comment: dont have nvidia optimus